# Extract a value from an array of data

Tags: python, arrays, bash, powershell, shell

I get such an array of data

```
[U8EUGGG1C32144101336_gulu, V5EUHHG1P12100100418_89011337751, V5EUHHG1P22111000028_89011337751]
```

How I can extract only this value `"89011337751"` and write it to a variable ?

Is it possible to do it with the `bash`, `powershell` or other scripts?

Comment: How do you determine you need exactly that value?

Comment: Will this always be the vaule? If so you can always do  if array[i].find(stringtofind) do the thing

Comment: is this a homework assignment or do you have two SO accounts; this question is identical to this [recently closed & deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75524189)

Comment: `[ value , value , value ]` is not a `bash` array; where are you getting this string from? a file? an application? something else?

Comment: i get this from application

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how you can achieve this in bash

```
#define the array
my_array=("[U8EUGGG1C32144101336_gulu]" "V5EUHHG1P12100100418_89011337751" "V5EUHHG1P22111000028_89011337751")

# extract the value and assign it to a variable
my_variable=${my_array[1]##*_}

# print the variable
echo $my_variable
```

Comment: its work, but my array with this format [U8EUGGG1C32144101336_gulu, V5EUHHG1P12100100418_89011337751, V5EUHHG1P22111000028_89011337751]. 
You write this [U8EUGGG1C32144101336_gulu]" "V5EUHHG1P12100100418_89011337751" "V5EUHHG1P22111000028_89011337751". If i try use your script for my format, its not work

Comment: my_array=(U8EUGGG1C32144101336_gulu V5EUHHG1P12100100418_89011337751 V5EUHHG1P22111000028_89011337751)
desired_value=$(echo "${my_array[@]}" | sed -E 's/.*_([0-9]+)($| .*)/\1/')
echo $desired_value